# Angular 2 - ошибка 404 после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: angular2

Проблема вот с чем - приложение работает отлично, роутинг реализован с помощью нативного Router. Но когда перезагружаю страницу и при это нахожусь на каком либо роуте, допустим /products/edit, то выходит страница 404 и приходится переходить на корневой адрес приложения. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Какой сервер используете NodeJS, Apache или еще что?

Comment: Используем Apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте в файл .htaccess добавить строку

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

или

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

Comment: да, FallbackResource помог

Answer (score 0):

Была аналогичная ситуация, но у меня не было .htaccess, я его добавил и прописал ErrorDocument 404 /index.html 
и все заработало!)